# Script for finding the sum of the last cell in specific columns

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make this Google script for Sheets so that finds the sum of the last values in F,N,R,S,T and inputs that value into the last cell in column U. The following works but I want the script to grab the last cell with a value in it from each of the 5 columns.

```
        function myFunction() {
      var sheetname = "SHEET1"; 
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetname);
    var num1 = sheet.getRange("F2710").getValue();
    var num2 = sheet.getRange("N2710").getValue();
     var num3 = sheet.getRange("R2710").getValue();
     var num4 = sheet.getRange("S2710").getValue();
    var num5 = sheet.getRange("T2710").getValue();
    sheet.getRange("U2710").setValue(num1+num2+num3+num4+num5);
}
```

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum of bottoms

You have to provide the sheet name and the sumrow and then rum getSumNow().

sumrow is one of the properties of the initial value object in the reduce function.

If you wish to  display the sum somewhere else the it is available with this method: obj.getSum();

```
function getSumNow() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var cols=[6,14,18,19,20];
  var obj=cols.reduce(function(a,c,i){
    a.sum+=sh.getRange(getLastRowInCol(c,sh,ss),c).getValue();
    return a;
  },{sumcol:21,sumrow:21,sum:0,getSum:function(){sh.getRange(this.sumrow,this.sumcol).setValue(this.sum);}}).getSum();
}
```

The function below was used in the above function so it had to be provided.

```
function getLastRowInCol(col,sh,ss){
  var ss=ss||SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=sh||ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col=col||sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  const rcA=sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues().reverse()
  let s=0;
  for(let i=0;i<rcA.length;i++) {
    if(rcA[i][0].toString().length==0) {
      s++;
    }else{
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length-s;
}
```

[Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

It appears that this is what you would prefer:

```
function getSumNow() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var cols=[6,14,18,19,20];
  var obj=cols.reduce(function(a,c,i){
    a.sum+=sh.getRange(getLastRowInCol(c,sh,ss),c).getValue();
    return a;
  },{sumcol:21,sumrow:getLastRowInCol(this.sumcol,sh,ss)+1,sum:0,getSum:function(){sh.getRange(this.sumrow,this.sumcol).setValue(this.sum);}}).getSum();
}
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong.  I see there are two functions.  I've tried running first getSumNow then getLastRowInCol funtions and nothing happens.  I also tried wrapping both in a function and nothing happens.  Even stranger...when I include it your code in with another function it does work but rewrites the last row of the column instead of inserting it in the last blank row of the column (which is the desired result).  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  I've edited the code above that I've added it to.

Comment: You said that you wanted the script to find the last cell of the five columns so I assumed that you would provide the row of the last cell to the function since it seemed that you didn't want the function to find it for you.

Comment: I looks like its kinda working now.  But It pastes the SUM in column 21 and row 21 according to `sumcol:21,sumrow:21`

Comment: Yes it does that in the first version.  I thought you were going to provide the row number for column 21 but the second version I just added puts the sum in the first empty cell just below the last cell in the column.

Comment: Cooper!  That is exactly what I needed!  Thank you.  Sorry I had trouble communicating that the first time.  I appreciate your time and skill! Thank you!